# How can I turn the "... is a script application. Are you sure you want to run it?" warnings in Coda off?

Tags: macos, coda

If I paste some code into Coda (for mac) and then change to the preview tab, it asks me:

```
Untitled2.php is a script application. are you sure you want to run it?
```

This is annoying. Of course I want to run it - I clicked preview. How can I turn this off?

Comment: Doesn't seem possible. I found no options, no `defaults`, no documentation, no nothing. Looking forward to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application "[Deeper](http://bit.ly/rr2vxa)" has an option for this:

[image]